# How can i export gwt project to external web server?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I have created a web application using google web toolkit, it works fine launching it from eclipse. I want to put it on my server so I compile it with `gwt compile` and put the war folder on server. Client works well but the rpc calls return "not found error" on javascript console. I feel like i missed one step: maybe I should launch java server for rpc first, but i don't understand how to do it.

Comment: Your app already runs on server which runs server-side code (servlets) and gives static to server. I assume that "not found error" occurs because of wrong routing. You must configure routing correctly in your WEB-INF/web.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWT-RPC requires a servlet container: Tomcat, Jetty, etc.

If your "server" is Apache HTTPD, Nginx, Lighttpd, etc. then it's not enough.

An alternative is to not use GWT-RPC so you can code your server-side in another language (PHP, Ruby, etc.) That requires much more work on GWT's client side though.

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to find a solution by installing Tomcat.